# Completeness in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, linear-algebra

While studying Matrix representation I found a topic about completeness for a basis by the equation:$
∑_{n}|ψ_n⟩⟨ψ_n|=1$

I don't understand the physical meaning behind it. Is it something to do with infinite basis vectors?

Comment: I don't think you'll get much *physical meaning* from it, but if you take an arbitrary state $|\psi\rangle$ and act on it with the completeness relation you will find that you get back that same state since you are just rewriting it as a sum over the basis vectors $|\psi_n\rangle$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you recall the projection operator, $\mathcal{P}$, which look like
$$\mathcal{P}=|\phi_n\rangle \langle \phi_n|$$

where $\{|\phi_i\rangle\}$ are assumed to be the basis set for the LVS. Then what this operator does is project a component of any arbitrary vector along with the basis $|\phi_n\rangle$.

What I'm trying to say, Given a vector
$$|\psi\rangle =\sum_i c_i|\phi_i\rangle $$
$$\mathcal{P}|\psi\rangle =\sum_ic_i|\phi_n\rangle \langle \phi_n|\phi_i\rangle=c_n|\phi_n\rangle  $$
That explain the projection operator.

Now If I project the along all its component,
$$\sum_i \mathcal{P_i}|\psi\rangle =\sum_i|\phi_i\rangle \langle\phi_i|\left(\sum_jc_j|\phi_j\rangle\right)=\sum_{i,j}c_j|\phi_i\rangle \langle \phi_i|\phi_j\rangle =|\psi\rangle $$
In other world,
$$\sum_i|\phi_i\rangle \langle \phi_i|=I$$
This is saying nothing but If I project the vector along all its basis vectors, I get the vector back.

Comment: Ok so if I'm not wrong what they mean by complete is given a state I can completely expand it into its basis vectors kind of like fourier series and they needed to clarify it because the basis chosen is sometimes infinite.

Answer (score 2):

This is just the statement that any state can be written as a linear combination of the elements in the basis.